# How can I add a FTP server to my small business.

Tags: ftp, file-management

I operate a two small stores for clothing but I have some accountants that share files via email. Last week we were hit with an electrical storm and it fried a few PC's at our separate location (manager had not installed power blocks that stop pc's from turning off). I did some research into a "FTP server" or file server which can hold files. I discussed with a the two managers and we agreed we would like to get a file server set up at each location and have employee's copy files they want saved to that server, my question is how do I do this? I am 52 years old and not very computer savvy.

Comment: You need a FTP server software. It depends on the software what you would need to do to configure it. What OS are you usually running (Windows, MacOS, Linux)?

Comment: We all use windows 7 and 10.

Comment: Have a look at http://www.wftpserver.com/ which is not free but it's intuitive, simple, and very robust. I can vouch for this product and highly recommend it as well. I have no affiliation with this company other than being a customer of their server product for one of the company's I support and another one I used to support. They will give you a free 30 day trial, provide you with support, and the cost not bad. You get FTP, FTPS, SFTP, HTTP and HTTPS interfaces into the server.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds from your description that you are quite a small business (no offence intended) and perhaps do not have much of an IT budget, although, as you have realised, keeping your data safe is of course very important to keeping your business running.

Do you have any sort of shared file storage between the computers in your business already?

You probably do not want an "ftp server" as such, as ftp is an effectively obsolete means of file transfer: files sent via ftp are not encrypted and therefore could potentially be read by any computer that they pass through as they travel over the internet (although exactly the same risk also applies to files sent via standard unencrypted email). If your business files contain any sort of confidential information or Personal Data, you do not want to transmit them "in the clear", even if the risk of interception may perhaps be (relatively) minimal.

Any sort of remotely accessible data storage should only use secure encrypted communication, such as https for a web-based system, or some sort of file sharing protocol running over ssh otherwise.

Running a file server of any sort requires some degree of system administration experience, in order to set up the server so as not to be accessible to unauthorised people, as well as periodic attention to keep the server software up to date with security fixes. If you are not sure that you can do this yourself, you may want to ask a local IT consultant to set up some sort of file server solution for you.

Possibly the very simplest solution, although perhaps not ideal, might be to purchase an external storage drive with "personal cloud storage" functionality (which is relatively simple to set up): in other words, you can access the contents of the drive from your various computers via the internet.

Personal cloud storage drives are available from many storage drive manufacturers: for example, "Seagate Personal Cloud" drives, "WD My Cloud" drives. You should be able to find specific models for sale on the websites of your preferred computer shops.

However, this still presents a potential single point of failure again in the event of electrical surge damage or hardware failure. Cloud-accessible storage drives are really only intended for personal use and are perhaps not ideal for even a small business.

A more robust solution would be to add a server computer in both of your locations, and synchronise the files between them over the internet, so that you have two copies in case of hardware failure again. This could perhaps be done fairly inexpensively using older or second-hand computers running Linux and using [rsync](https://rsync.samba.org/) to keep the data in sync, although you would need to learn a little about Linux in order to set up such a system.

A similar solution would also be possible using Windows, but may be somewhat more expensive to implement because of licensing costs.

Comment: We used to use DropBox was it was compromised.

the Files we are wanting to back up are mostly PDF's, excel spread sheets, and some minor accounting files. 

"purchase an external storage drive with "personal cloud storage" functionality" can you expand upon this further please? This idea sounds very promising, and I can get ahold of some older computers and set them up running linux, can't be that hard but can you also explain this further please? Both idea's sound very interesting and if I can keep my cost relatively low then I will be happy.

Comment: FTP is an old protocol but certainly not obsolete to get files onto a server. There is also FTPS and SFTP (though there is a big difference here) to protect the data stream. As for third party service, you could e.g. rent a server or use a service like [BlackBlaze](https://www.backblaze.com/business-backup.html). Usually services like DropBox, OneDrive and Google Drive offer some form of business account as well. Getting a device like a ready to go Synology NAS might also be an option.

Comment: I have added examples of some personal cloud storage drives which you should be able to find for sale at your preferred computer shops.

Comment: I am afraid that I cannot advise of the exact details of how to set up a Linux server to share your files with your computers, but searching Stack Exchange sites (or elsewhere) should provide answers with more specific details.

Comment: @seth You are correct that sftp and ftps are alternative and secure means to transfer files, I merely wanted to point out that "standard" ftp is not encrypted, and therefore not secure, in case the original poster happened to find old tutorials still on the internet about how to set up a basic ftp server.